# Unable to see Macintosh HD, error 69770 on Running First Aid

Tags: macos, disk-utility

I have deleted Linux partition from my drive and now I cannot see it, only empty drive.
After typing `diskutil list`:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *28.0 GB    disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         27.7 GB    disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                                                   *2.0 TB     disk1

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +27.7 GB    disk2
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume PCI SSD - Data          6.2 GB     disk2s1
   2:                APFS Volume Update                  176.1 KB   disk2s2
   3:                APFS Volume Preboot                 88.5 MB    disk2s3
   4:                APFS Volume Recovery                529.0 MB   disk2s4
   5:                APFS Volume VM                      2.1 GB     disk2s5
   6:                APFS Volume PCI SSD                 11.0 GB    disk2s6
```

`sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk1`:

```
       start        size  index  contents
           0           1         
           1           1         Pri GPT header
           2          32         Pri GPT table
          34  4000797293      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  4000797327          32         Sec GPT table
  4000797359           1         Sec GPT header
```

I have temporary OS on `disk2`.

`Disk2` is uninitialised:
[image]

Comment: There are dozens of similar question on here - see if any help https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=FFFFFFFF

Comment: Tried many of given posts with no result, please see last photo added to reference. Issue with /dev/disk2.

Comment: @Noz_Char disk2 is a disk image used for Recovery HD. It should have no effect on your normal boot.

Comment: Sorry meant disk1.

Comment: I honestly only care about few files inside it, which had not been backed up. I only care to get them and recover partition to default state/erase it.